# Powershell & C# PostMessage

Tags: c#, powershell, winapi, postmessage

I am trying to add Deanna's C# [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11365605/8021428) that parses a string and uses PostMessage to send it to a Windows handle with the excellent Powershell code utilizing the WinAPI to manipulate applications [posted to Reddit here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/63hh1k/manipulating_textboxesbuttons_in_other/).

Unfortunately, I do not have a C# background, and am having some difficulty debugging the new code. While it compiles without error- and sends input to the specified application- the input it sends is the system date and time. Twice! It also does not send the [Enter] key after parsing the text string.

Any direction?

```
Add-Type @"
  using System;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Text;

public class WindowHelper {
 [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
 [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
 static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
 [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
 public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
 [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
 public static extern bool SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, StringBuilder lParam);
 [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
 public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(int hWnd, int Msg, int wparam,int lparam);
 [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
 static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, int wParam, string lParam);
 [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
 static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
 [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
 static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
 static extern IntPtr GetDlgItem(IntPtr hDlg, int nIDDlgItem);
 [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
 static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);
 const int WM_GETTEXT = 0x000D;
 const int WM_SETTEXT = 0x000C;
 const int WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = 0x000E;
 const int BM_CLICK = 0x00F5;
 const Int32 WM_CHAR = 0x0102;
 const Int32 WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
 const Int32 WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
 const Int32 VK_RETURN = 0x0D;

 public static void SelectControl(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
    }
 public static void ClickButton(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        PostMessage(hWnd, (int)BM_CLICK, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

    }
 public static IntPtr GetControlById(IntPtr ParentHwnd,int ControlID)
        {
            return GetDlgItem(ParentHwnd, ControlID);
        }
 public static void SetControlText(IntPtr hWnd, string sString)
        {
            SendMessage(hWnd, (int)WM_SETTEXT, sString.Length, new StringBuilder(sString));
        }
 public static string GetControlText(IntPtr hWnd)
        {
            StringBuilder controlText = new StringBuilder();
            Int32 size = SendMessage((int)hWnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0).ToInt32();
            if (size > 0)
            {
            controlText = new StringBuilder(size + 1);
            SendMessage(hWnd, (int)WM_GETTEXT, controlText.Capacity, controlText);
            }
            return controlText.ToString();
        }
 public static IntPtr FindHWndByCaptionAndProcessID(string windowTitle,int ProcessID)
        {
            IntPtr retIntPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            int maxCount = 9999;
            int ct = 0;
            IntPtr prevChild = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr currChild = IntPtr.Zero;
            while(true && ct < maxCount)
            {
                currChild = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, prevChild, null, null);
                if (currChild == IntPtr.Zero) break;
                    if (IsWindowVisible(currChild)) {
                    if(GetControlText(currChild) == windowTitle)
                    {
                    uint procID = 0;
                    GetWindowThreadProcessId(currChild, out procID);
                    if (procID == ProcessID) {
                        retIntPtr = currChild;
                        break;
                    }
                    }
            }
            prevChild = currChild;
            ++ct;
         }
        return retIntPtr;
    }
 public static void SendKeys(string text, int hWnd)
    {
        foreach (char c in "text")
        {
            // char ascii value in decimal
            int charValue = c;

            // char ascii value in hex
            string hexValue = charValue.ToString("X");

            IntPtr val = new IntPtr((Int32)c);

            PostMessage(new IntPtr(hWnd), WM_KEYDOWN, val, new IntPtr(0));
            PostMessage(new IntPtr(hWnd), WM_CHAR, val, new IntPtr(0));
            PostMessage(new IntPtr(hWnd), WM_KEYUP, val, new IntPtr(0));

        }
        PostMessage(new IntPtr(hWnd), WM_KEYDOWN, new IntPtr(VK_RETURN), new IntPtr(0));
        PostMessage(new IntPtr(hWnd), WM_KEYUP, new IntPtr(VK_RETURN), new IntPtr(0));
    }
}
"@
$Text = 'testing'
Pause
$Notepad = Get-Process "Notepad"
$NotepadId = $Notepad.Id
Write-Host $NotepadId
$NotepadHWnd=[WindowHelper]::FindHWndByCaptionAndProcessID("Untitled - Notepad",$NotepadId)
if([int]$NotepadHWnd -eq 0){Start-Sleep -seconds 1}
Write-Host $NotepadHWnd
Pause
[WindowHelper]::SelectControl($NotepadHWnd)
[WindowHelper]::SendKeys($Text,$NotepadHWnd)
```

Comment: Why? Don't you need UI Automation?

Comment: For the automation we're trying to build the UI is not exposed to an active desktop session.

Comment: I don't really see the relevance of that comment. If that is so, then why do you think that faking input through powershell will get the job done. It's amazing how many times a day this question gets asked in vain.

Comment: Faking input through Powershell works for this application. We've had success using VBScript's SendKeys. However, that's not practical at scale, as there's no way to set the application as the active window. This is where we started looking for alternatives and turned to PostMessage.

Comment: Forget it. You don't want my advice. Good luck with your debugging.

Comment: Beg pardon, David, but I don't have any control over the development of this application. I'm a systems administrator responsible for its infrastructure. At times that requires interfacing with the application itself, which used to be a standalone OS that was ported to Windows in the early 2000's. I wish it had an API- something, anything- but it only accepts keystrokes.

Comment: I don't think you know what UI Automation is. Still, you seem set on this course. So be it.